# WCF Service returning "requested service '...' could not be activated" the first time it's accessed from an MVC site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, exception

We have a WCF service (with no security) that is being accessed by an MVC3 website.

On the developer machines we have no problems with it but when our TeamCity setup builds the central version and deploys it under IIS7 the first time we load the MVC3 site and it accesses the WCF service - the service call returns the message:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://localhost:83/ABCStaticData/StaticDataService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.**

If we immediately hit the same site again, everything works fine.

The server stack track when it throws the error is:

Server stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
at ABC.StaticData.Editor.StaticDataServiceProxy.IStaticDataService.GetAllMarkets()
at ABC.StaticData.Editor.StaticDataServiceProxy.StaticDataServiceClient.GetAllMarkets() in c:\BuildAgent\work\55a3bcc468adcccb\StaticData\ABC.StaticData.Editor\Service References\StaticDataServiceProxy\Reference.cs:line 3195
at ABC.StaticData.Editor.Controllers.MarketsController.<>c__DisplayClass22.<.ctor>b__13() in c:\BuildAgent\work\55a3bcc468adcccb\StaticData\ABC.StaticData.Editor\Controllers\MarketsController.cs:line 263
at ABC.StaticData.Editor.Controllers.MarketsController.Index() in c:\BuildAgent\work\55a3bcc468adcccb\StaticData\ABC.StaticData.Editor\Controllers\MarketsController.cs:line 306
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing the problem or where to start looking?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention the first that if we then don't access the site for a while and then go back, it gives the same error - then works again the second time.

UPDATE2: This is the event log entry text:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/3043589
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/ABCStaticData/StaticDataService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.IsDefined(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.HasAttribute(MemberInfo member, Type type)
   at Ninject.Selection.Heuristics.StandardInjectionHeuristic.ShouldInject(MemberInfo member)
   at Ninject.Selection.Selector.<>c__DisplayClassa.<SelectMethodsForInjection>b__9(IInjectionHeuristic h)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Ninject.Selection.Selector.<SelectMethodsForInjection>b__8(MethodInfo m)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.MethodReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan plan)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateNewPlan>b__0(IPlanningStrategy s)
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.CreateNewPlan(Type type)
   at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent)
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.BaseNinjectServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 3248
```

Just another point that we're developing using .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Comment: Are you sure? What is the appropriate event log entry text?

Comment: Event log entry is above now - the exception tree when tracing out was only the first one and pushing out the inner exception from the catch gave a null reference.

Comment: I am not in a convenient place to validate, but it looks like ASP.NET is running under framework v4.0, given this message in your exception:  `from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0`.  Are you sure .NET 4.5 is installed correctly on the server?  Also, you know framework 4.5 is not yet supported for production applications, right?

Comment: @ChrisShain I'll check with the team-member who setup the teamcity build/deploy server but note that it does work the second time you hit the service.  We can repeat the same error by just browsing to the .svc on the server itself - but again, it's fine the second time you browse to the same .svc file.  And yes, we are aware of the 4.5/production support situation.

Comment: Also, does the same happen on dev machines the first time if you kill the local hosting process?  You can access that by clicking on the icon in the system tray.

Comment: No it doesn't - we're using IIS on the dev machines also.  If we kill IIS or w3wp.exe and then browse to the .svc file, it comes up fine first time.

Comment: We've just checked and .NET 4.5 is definitely installed on the build/deploy server.  But it's clearly trying to use 4.0 on first access as AsyncStateMachineAttribute is obviously not in mscorlib from 4.0 but is in the 4.5 version.

Comment: What is the target runtime of a pool the service is running under?

Comment: The target runtime of the app pool is ".NET Framework v4.0.30319".  Note that there isn't a v4.5 available in the list on either the deployment server of the dev machines.

Answer (score 38):

I've just manage to solve similar problem of random 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException' (thrown exception, then run on second hit.). The reason for the exception in my case was lack of memory on the server. To confirm the memory problem, you can do following:

Application calling web service:

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'XXX' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

WCF trace log: nothing logged.

On server hosting wcf service (the same as the calling application btw) in event logs except lot of crap info I've found:

Custom event details:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/58366981
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service 'xxx' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (xxx bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.. ---> System.InsufficientMemoryException: Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (xxx bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element.
```

So solution for me was:
 1. add more ram
 2. release some of ram (temporary solution)
 3. update web config of the web service:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment ... minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: great, the RAM was my problem too!!

Comment: #1 was infeasible for me (bureaucratic hurdles). Tried #3, working like a charm, at least for now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem too and just simply put

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment  minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1"/>
```

under

`<system.serviceModel>`

And everything works fine.

Comment: minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1"

Comment: Your `serviceHostingEnvironment ` tag is not closed, it should end with `/>` rather than `>`.

Answer (score 2):

I've hit the same "Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute'", which I found out was because I had built my application using VS 2012 RTM, but then tried to deploy it on a machine that only had 4.5 Beta.  The AsyncStateMachineAttribute is a new type added after Beta.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem too, what I did is:

- Go to the directory in the file system where the service resides
- you will have 2 files for the service

  - yourService.svc
  - yourService.svc.cs
- Open the file yourService.svc and make sure that your service is configured, and the code behind looks like this:

  ```
  <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="YourNamespace.yourService.svc" CodeBehind="yourService.svc.cs" %>
  ```

I fixed my issue that way. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you install IIS after installing Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). To fix it, simply run the following command:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r
```

Source: [IIS Hosted Service Fails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is .svc extension registered under IIS?

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Guess it's since it load the second time. Was to quick to post my answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Memory of the server you are hosting the services on is not full.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today and instead of RAM being the problem it was disk space. After freeing up space, I had to restart the Application Pool and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out to be the Authentication setting in IIS was configured incorrectly.  As such the authentication failure was blocking the initial request preventing the service from activating.

Answer (score -1):

Everytime I have the same problem, I restart my computer and it works well. It frees up memory

Comment: We can't restart the PC every time this error occurred. Isn't it?

Comment: I agree with you, we cant afford to restart it every day or so. Having exhausted all the above suggestions and still does not work. We forget the simple fact that the machine needs to restart after running for weeks to free up resources. And Microsoft recommends that: 
"Restart regularly
 Restart your PC at least once a week, especially if you use it a lot. It is a good way to clear out its memory and ensure that any errant processes and services that started running get shut down."
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/optimize-Windows-7-for-better-performance?72a92270