# The requested service could not be activated, WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am new to ASP.NET programming.

I am creating an e-commerce system like takealot.

My problem is that whenever I run my home page, it runs fine. However when I click shop (to go to the shop page), it crashes and gives the error:

> The requested service could not be activated.

I googled it and there aren't many solutions.

I think it's because my service isn't running, but I have my property of my project to start the service and the webpage together. So why isn't my service running?  Or is it some other problem?

My website is dependent on my service, I configured the settings to run the service and website together, but it doesn't run my website. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343563/wcf-service-returning-requested-service-could-not-be-activated-the-first) says that it could be a RAM issue. Are you facing this issue locally or on a web server?

Comment: @Tasos K. I don't have a RAM problem. Sorry I'm new to this, what do you mean by locally or a web server?

Comment: Are you running in your PC or it is deployed somewhere?

Comment: It seems that the service working improperly. Which project template do you use to build the e-commerce system? If the issue relates to WCF, please post a complete project structure details and WCF configuration.

Comment: I'm running it on my PC.

Comment: what is the service type of the backend service? if indeed, I think we should enable windows features for hosting WCF service in IIS.  I reckon something wrong with the service working state.

Comment: @Candyfloss https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5ukf.png

Comment: @Abraham Qian I have all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, but did you include something like this in your HomeController?

```
    public ActionResult shop()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

It's something I also often forget.

Edit:
Does it look like this? (Just in in English because this is German)
[service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqgcB.png)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Does it look like on the picture I added to my comment?

Comment: No, it different. The error comes in Visual Studio.